# For multivariate probability distributions, what are "medians" and "percentiles"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, integral-equations

It is well known that for one dimensional random variables $$\cases{pdf(t) : 1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}pdf(t)dt\\cdf(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}pdf(\tau)d\tau}$$
The k:th percentile is the solution $t_k$ for which:
$$cdf(t_k)=\frac k {100}$$
Where the well known special case the *median*, $k=50$.

---

However for multivariate distributions, how can one define these things uniquely without ending up with manifolds that are dependent on the coordinate system?

---

If it is not possible to do, is there still any use ( practical applications ) to this generalization which results in larger-than-0-dimensional level sets?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is: "Undefined quantities".

Comment: @Did : Okay, maybe I should rephrase the question to "how would it make sense to define..."?